# Laravel 5 Flash messages not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

My flash messages are not displaying on the view. I have tried post SO questions but didn't worked.
Here is my controller code:

```
use Session;
//other code
//my code to set flash message and redirect it

    \Session::flash('message', $message);  
    return redirect('admin/groups/add');
```

My View code:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
 <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alert_danger">
   {!!Session::get('message')!!}
 </div>
@endif
```

I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: [`$request->session()->flash('message', 'rtm');`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#flash-data)

Comment: Is it redirect twice?

Comment: no redirecting it once only

Answer (score 0):

in your controller :

```
 use Session;

 public function myfunction(){
     return redirect('admin/groups/add')->with('message', $message);
 }
```

in your blade view :

```
@if(session()->has('message'))
 <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alert_danger">
   {{{{session('message')}}}}
 </div>
@endif
```

Comment: use `{{session('message')}}`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, add

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors('Password is incorrect.');
```

In view, add

```
@if($errors->first())
   <p class="alert alert-danger">{{$errors->first()}}</p>            
@endif
```